# Providing action to only the clicked button in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show, ng-hide

I'm working with ng-repeat .In the ng-repeat i'm repeating panel.The panel body consist of two part .First part is a paragragh which i fetch from the database using $http.get(). In the second part i have a button (edit button).When i click the edit button the paragraph in the first part should be hidden and text-area should appear with the content in the paragraph as default.But when i'm trying to achieve this im getting an idea when i click one edit button all of my paragragh hides and the textarea appear .How can i restrict it .

```js
$scope.editorEnabled = false;

$scope.enableEditor = function() {
  $scope.editorEnabled = true;
};
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="(key,rec) in recordcomment">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          heading
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" style="background-color:white;">
          <p ng-hide="editorEnabled">{{rec.comment}}</p>
          <textarea ng-model="rec.comment" ng-show="editorEnabled"></textarea>
          <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="enableEditor()">Edit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="panel-body" style="background-color:white;">
          <p ng-hide="rec.editorEnabled">{{rec.comment}}</p>
          <textarea ng-model="rec.comment" ng-show="rec.editorEnabled"></textarea>
          <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="enableEditor(rec)">Edit</button>
        </div>

     $scope.enableEditor = function(context) {
          context.editorEnabled = true;
     };
```

Use **rec** instead of **this**

Because **this** means current context of **ng-repeat** directive..

So to make it effective we need to modify the object...

Hence we need to pass it as i have use **rec** in function param

Try this in case do comment

Comment: hey bro i got one more dbt

Answer (score 1):

> Add the `editorEnabled` object with `ng-rpeat` object. so it will be consider with the array object. and you can pass `this` current object via `click function()` and set true/false the `editorEnabled` object.

Code looks like.

```
        <div class="panel-body" style="background-color:white;">
          <p ng-hide="rec.editorEnabled">{{rec.comment}}</p>
          <textarea ng-model="rec.comment" ng-show="rec.editorEnabled"></textarea>
          <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="enableEditor(this)">Edit</button>
        </div>

         $scope.enableEditor = function(context) {
             context.editorEnabled = true;
         };
```

Comment: when i click the button no action happens

Comment: Put alert the function and check . also check your console have any issue. if issue there then just change to this line as ` ng-click="enableEditor(rec)">`

Comment: hey i got one more dbt

Comment: What doubt, tell me.

Comment: is there any way to make that textarea active when we click the edit. i tried with active class